# `Re[z]` Command

Tags: complex

Suppose we have complex number $z=a+i b$, where $a$ and $b$ are variables.

Now, if we want real part of $z$, then in mathematica we use `Re[z]` command. But this command is not working (because $a$ and $b$ are not fixed real numbers).

`Re[expr]` is left unevaluated if expr is not a numeric quantity. (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html)

How do we get `Re[z]`$=a$ as solution?

Comment: See "Properties & Relations" in the documentation for `Re`.  It shows various uses of `ComplexExpand` with respect to `Re`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z = a + I b;
ComplexExpand[Re[z]]
```

> a

Hope that helps.

Comment: But what is the difference between `ComplexExpand[Re[z]]` and `Re[ComplexExpand[z]]`??

Comment: Command `ComplexExpand[Re[z]]` gives me correct result, but `Re[ComplexExpand[z]]` is not working

Comment: `ComplexExpand[z]` has not got any work to do. If you try `ComplexExpand[z^2]` then it does do some work. Have a good look at the documentation. What would you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3):

The rewrite rules behind `ComplexExpand` assume all undefined symbols in the expression are real.

```
ComplexExpand[z]
```

is just

```
z
```

Thus,

```
Re[ComplexExpand[z]]
```

first gets rewritten as

```
Re[z]
```

and no further rewrite is possible because `Re` has no rule for this case. But `ComplexExpand` inspects the structure of the expression it's given. It recognizes that it can rewrite `Re[z]` as `z`.

*Mathematica* is a language for rewriting mathematical expressions based on recognizing their structure. Sometimes those rewrites seem to act like "commands", but it is misleading to think of them that way.